# Live chat on Rails app through Faye but on Passenger with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, websocket, faye

Our website is currently running our Rails web app on Passenger with Apache.

Recently, there is a requirement to do live chatting. As such we are planning to deploy Faye by following this article (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails--net-22600).

However, since Apache does not support websocket, we are not able to use any of such implementation.

We preferred not to change the webserver since additional effort for testing and migration will be involve. Is there any other way to get around this problem?

Appreciate any helps from Rails expert out that.

-Jax

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the answer, though somewhere I read that you should use redis for faye to run it with apache/passenger beacuse they can't be run in single process and share memory, checkout faye-redis gem. Than probably faye server should be run as separate process, and Apache configured to send ':9292/faye' to it.

Comment: It states that here: http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html. And I quote "Some servers supported by Faye, such as Passenger, use a multi-process model rather than using threads or events in the same process. For those servers, the default in-memory engine will not work; you should use a multi-process engine such as the Redis backend."